# Refresh after submit and avoid message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to refresh my page after I click on a submit button or do submit by using shortcut keys provided. I also need to avoid the message which i get from the browser.
I am submitting some text so i get a message that entered data might get lost. However it does not.
Below is the code for my submit.

```
<input accesskey="s" class="button" id="issue-comment-add-submit" name="Add" title="Press Alt+Shift+s to submit this form" value="Add" type="submit">
```

Please can someone provide a solution using javascript or Jquery

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the exact message you are getting?

Comment: How does the form get submitted without reloading the page? Ajax? Or submit in another (i)Frame?

Comment: I get this message "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

Comment: @Nic I think this is using Ajax or REST Api but i am not sure .

Comment: If you are not sure how it is submitted, how are we supposed to help you with your problem?

Comment: @Nic , I am writing a javascript for a tool JIRA , here the script runs when the page is loaded however when i add a comment the page does not load . So I need to reload when the comment is submitted.

Comment: @Nic I am new to JS, Jquery and Ajax , can help me in identifying how the form is submitted ?

Comment: Use Firebug, look at the form's `method` and `target` attribute, look into the Firebug console for AJAX requests.

Comment: @Nic Thank you :) method=post , there is no target attribute but there is a action attribute (it uses webwork) which call a java method .

Comment: @Nic I see 2 requests under XHR when i submit .